# MVC 5 @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having some issues with some data filtering ; I want, from the following dropdown menu, to be able to display a list of projects by approval or not.

When the user creates a new project one of the fields is "approved", which is a boolean. That checkbox is left not checked and when the project has a Go the user picks that checkbox as an approved project.

Basically, I want, when the user picks the option "Approved", to be redirected to the list of already approved projects.

How can I do that?

```html
           <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Project Execution <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li> @Html.ActionLink("Approved", "Index", "NEWPROJECTs")</li>                    
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("On Going", "Index", "NEWPROJECTs")</li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("List", "Index", "PROJECTEXECUTIONs")</li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Route Parameters**

If you have a single controller action that handles one or more of these operations, then you'll likely need to supply a route value to determine what data you should be filtering by:

```
public ActionResult NewProjects(string filter)
{
     // Check the filter that was used and filter the content that you
     // will pass to the view accordingly

     // Get your projects prior to filtering
     var projects = _context.Projects;

     switch (filter)
     {
         case "ONGOING":
             projects = projects.Where(p => p.Status == "ONGOING");
         break;       
         default:
             projects = projects.Where(p => p.Status == "APPROVED");
         break;
     }

     return View(projects);
}
```

Then when you build your Action Links, simply specify the `filter` as a route value so that your controller action can consume it and properly filter your data:

```
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Approved", "Index", "NEWPROJECTs", new { filter = "APPROVED"})
</li>                    
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink("On Going", "Index", "NEWPROJECTs", new { filter = "ONGOING"})
</li>
```

Comment: That's just an example that might indicate how you are populating your data (it could be anything and is just there for example purposes), you could easily replace any of those calls with pure SQL / ADO.NET calls.